# In Google Sheets, I want to populate cells in Column A with certain conditions, based on the contents of column B

Tags: google-sheets

In this sheet,
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MR0n1FoutASbuwiNJS7FrcQhxHF6Bo03oVs9RZPo9g4/edit?usp=sharing

I am trying to have column B be populated with cell values equal to is today's date or tomorrow's date, by referencing column F.

Then, I am trying to have column A be populated with the contents of column E, based on if the column E's item is for today or tomorrow (Basically if the item's corresponding date shows up in B).

I've tried playing with index, lookup and filter but I cannot manage to get the formula right, and when using index and lookup there are many empty cells in between the dates.
I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added a sheet ("Erik Help") with the following formula in A1:

```
=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(FILTER(E:F,(F:F=TODAY())+(F:F=TODAY()+1))))
```

That one formula returns all results you wanted to see.

#### Explanation:

The key part to understand is the condition that FILTER is using to filter in entries; and that is (...) + (...). The plus sign is the equivalent of OR in an array. So it's basically saying, "Filter in all results from E:F where (F:F = today) OR (F:F = tomorrow)." And if there is no match at all found for that OR condition, IFERROR will just return nothing (rather than an error).

#### Reference:

- [FILTER](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197?hl=en)

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you so much Erik, studying your formula.

Comment: Happy to help. The key part to understand is the condition that FILTER is using to filter in entries; and that is (...) + (...).  The plus sign is the equivalent of OR in an array. So it's basically saying, "Filter in all results from E:F where (F:F = today) OR (F:F = tomorrow)." And if there is no match at all found for that OR condition, IFERROR will just return nothing (rather than an error).